# Stream of outer loop but collect to inner loop objects list

Tags: java, java-stream

I have an outer and inner loops.
They look like:

```
List<InnerObject> result = new ArrayList<>(innerObjects.size());
        for (OuterObject outerObject : outerObjects) {
            for (InnerObject innerObject : innerObjects) {
                if (someBooleanMethod(innerObject, outerObject)) {
                    result.add(innerObject);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

As you can see for each outer object I loop over the inner list and check the items and if they are equal by my checking I add the inner object to the result list.

I want to rewrite it using Stream API but I am facing a problem that I can't collect it to list of Inner objects.

The solution below works almost correctly but it creates a list of OuterObjects instead of Inner.

```
  List<OuterObject> result = outerObjects.stream()
                    .filter(outerObject -> innerObjects().stream()
                            .anyMatch(innerObject -> someBooleanMethod(innerObject, outerObject).
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

How to rewrite it in order to get a list of `InnerObjects`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just stream over the inner `List`:

```
List<InnerObject> result = 
    innerObjects.stream()
                .filter(innerObject -> outerObjects.stream()
                                                   .anyMatch(outerObject -> someBooleanMethod(innerObject, outerObject)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or if you must stream over the outer `List`, `map` each `OuterObject` to the first matching `InnerObject`:

```
List<InnerObject> result = 
    outerObjects.stream()
                .map(outerObject -> innerObjects.stream()
                                                .filter(innerObject -> someBooleanMethod(innerObject, outerObject))
                                                .findFirst()
                                                .orElse(null))
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Will it be equivalent to iterating each outer element?
I mean for each outer element I look over the inner list
but here looks like for each inner element I look over the outer list.
Will the behavior be the same?

Comment: @OleksandrRiznyk I added a solution that sttreams over the outer List in case you prefer that.

Comment: thanks a lot it is a perfect solution!
So are both your solutions are equivalent to each other? 
If so - do they have the same efficiency?

Comment: @OleksandrRiznyk it's better to use `for`s as you did. Personally, your version is more readable and more maintainable

Comment: @OleksandrRiznyk the answer to that depends on `someBooleanMethod`. If each inner object has a different outer object matching it, both solutions should be the same. On the other hand, if one outer element matches all inner elements, the first solution will return all the inner elements, while the second solution will return just the first inner element (assuming no other outer elements match any of the other inner elements)

Comment: @OleksandrRiznyk no they are not equivalent and actually, neither does what your loops do. It could still be that one of them is suitable to your task, depending on what `someBooleanMethod` actually does. And well, all of them are rather inefficient. But for better answers, we would need to know more about your actual task, e.g. why you call them “inner” and “outer” when there is no such relationship, actually.

Comment: @Holger, Thank you guys, actually I am new to this project and it has such a complex logic for me for now so I can't understand what is the relationship between that loops and why it was designed that way. Anyway thank you very much